# Limit of a composite function at a point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, functions

I am reading Real analysis by Denlinger and there comes a theorem -

> Suppose $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}g(x)=u_0$ and $\lim\limits_{u\to u_0}f(u)=L$, where $x_0$ and $u_0$ are cluster points of $D(g)$ and $D(f)$ respectively, and $g(x)\in D(f)-{\{u_0}\}$,$\forall  
> x\in D(g)$ in some deleted neighborhood of $x_0$.Then
> $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(g(x))=\lim\limits_{u\to u_0}f(u)=L$

I have understood the proof but not understand a condition in the theorem which is

> $g(x)\in D(f)-{\{u_0}\}$,$\forall  
> x\in D(g)$ in some deleted neighborhood of $x_0$.

But I don't understand the why this happen in the deleted neighborhood of $x_0$? Like in proof this condition is used.

Ex- $g(x) =
\begin{cases}
x,  & 0\leq x\leq 4 \\
4, & 4<x<8 \\ x-4, & 8\leq x
\end{cases}$
$f(u)=u+2$
Suppose I want to find $\lim\limits_{x\to 6}f(g(x))$ using the theorem.
Then, $\lim\limits_{x\to 6}g(x)=4$.
We see that $g(x)\in D(f)-{\{4\}}$. But in theorem they say that there should be a deleted neighborhood of $6\;s.t.\;g(x)\in D(f)-{\{4\}}$. But by definition of $g(x)$, every deleted neighborhood of $6$ has $g(x)=4$ as $g(x)$ is constant in $[4,8]$. So this composite function does not met the conditions of theorem. But graphically it satisfy the conclusion of the theorem.

Please tell me how this happen because the condition stated in theorem is used in its proof.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a nice exercise to show that the condition

> $g(x)\in D(f)-{\{u_0}\}$, $\ \forall  
> x\in D(g)$ in some deleted neighborhood of $x_0$,

is not necessary when $u_0\in D(f)$ and $f$ is continuous at $u_0$. This is precisely what happened in your example ($f$ is continuous at $4$).

Still, this condition is crucial in the case $f$ is not continuous at $u_0$. Considering the functions $f$ and $g$ in your example, let us see what happens when $f$ is not continuous at $4$, so let us modify it to
$$
f(u) = \left\{\begin{array}{rl} u+2, & \mbox{if } u\neq 4 \\
10, & \mbox{if } u=4\end{array}\right..
$$
Then, we may easily verify that $\lim_{u\to 4} f(u) = 6$ and $\lim_{x\to 6} f(g(x)) = 10$.